# How can I receive notifications on my phone when some writes on a card?

Tags: trello, notifications, tracking

I want to get notifications on my phone when some adds a comment to a board or card. What settings do I have to change in order to achieve this?

Comment: You get the notifications via mail?

Answer (score 1):

Trello has just added a subscribe function on cards.

So you can now get notifications on nearly anything that changes.

Details of how to subscribe to events are here http://blog.trello.com/introducing-subscribe-get-notifications-for-any-card/